# Distributing a Python/Django app and handling database replication

Tags: mysql, database, python, django, failover

We have developed a Python/Django app which we would like to distribute to clients, so they can run it locally (on a VM). We are doing this so they can still use the app if their internet connection dies, and it will just 're-sync' to the master database in our DC.

We were looking at MySQL/PostgreSQL replication, but they seem to have trouble with automatic failover, which is a must. Right now, we would have about 10-15 clients running this software locally, but we would like to be able to scale to much more. What is the best way of doing this (and with minimal code changes)?

Answer (score 0):

Offline use and re-sync would need a lot of conflict resolution logic - probably not something you'd want to let the database engine's built-in replication handle.

You'd still need to implement the conflict resolution parts, but maybe look at a distributable non-relational database (Mongo, Couch, Cassandra, etc), which might fit a bit better with what you're trying to do and let you dodge writing all the replication logic from scratch.